# Handling JButton event in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, event-handling

I just started using netbeans IDE to layout my interface, 
the problem is that i can't figure out how to link my JButton instance with the actual JButton that i've dragged into to my JPanel.

If i double click the button the event handler code will appear inside the JFrame class, i don't want that, what i want is the JPanel that owns the button to handle the event, not the JFrame.

Is that possible ? What i want is the same IBOutlet pattern used in iOS programming,

Thanks everybody.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without code. On the other hand, it will be hard to go through and understand your code with all the fooforall that NetBeans will have added to it. :(

Comment: There's nothing wrong so far. I have a JButton called 'run' that belongs to a JPanel, i want to handle the event inside the JPanel class, not inside the top JFrame(netbeans put everything inside the damn JFrame)...

Comment: My suggestion: don't use NetBeans to generate your Swing code. Create it yourself by hand, and have full control over what goes where and what does what.

Comment: Just figured it out.

Don't drag the JPanel directly from the palette, instead just go to your project tree and add a new JPanel Form...now everything will be inside that panel class.

@ Hovercraft Full Of Eels No, i'll not waste my time coding swing layout managers, thanks.

Comment: *"i'll not waste my time coding swing layout managers"*  You'd prefer to waste your time fighting your IDE?  GUI development, even using an IDE, will become a lot quicker & easier once the developer understands how the layouts work, & how they can be combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the given question, much details are not available, with the given details, here are my suggestions,

1. I suppose in netbeans, you created a new `JFrame` Form and then added a `JPanel` to it and then a button to it, in this case, the `jpanel` to which you added the button is inside the `jFrame` so ultimately you need not wonder if the code is produced in the `jFrame` class. 
   In this case I suggest you, instead of creating a  `jFrame` form, create a `jPanel` form and add the button, I hope this is most probably you want.
2. As @Hovercraft full of eels suggested, "don't use NetBeans to generate your Swing code"